# Angular2 application minification and tree-shaking with Webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, minify, rollup, tree-shaking

In my Angular2 application (ES6 spec), I am using WebPack with a common config which is extended in dev and prod config. In my prod config, I would like to also use uglification after doing tree shaking.

How do I make it happen? Any sample/link to configure this would be great help.

Would `UglifyJsPlugin` work with ES6 script? Would it need `ES6-Shim`?

Is it necessary to use Rollup for tree shaking? Should I completely shift to RollUp for the same?

Sorry, for a loaded question.
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you start your project with `angular-cli`. It has all the scaffolding prepared, tested and working.

You can simply start a development server with `ng serve` and build artifacts with `ng build`. It includes AOT, tree-shaking, minification, etc.

Refer to the [official documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, Vladimir! I would love to do that but, unfortunately, that not an option. All i have to do now is make this work. :(